# Assign columns in pandas dataframe based on multiple comparisons with rows of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to match dates in a dataframe against start and end dates in another dataframe and to include the name and dates of the time interval in the output.

Specifically: Given a Python pandas dataframe (`shas`) with a `date` column, I would like to assign new columns with information on the corresponding named time interval (i.e. iteration).
These `iterations` are described in a separate dataframe with `start`, `end` and `name` columns.

I've come up with the following code, which works, but seems unelegant (especially the `.iterrows()` call).

Do you have suggestions for alternatives that are more pandas*ish*?

```py
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

iterations = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['Sprint 1', 'Sprint 2'],
    'start': [datetime.date(2022, 11, 1), datetime.date(2023, 1, 1)],
    'end': [datetime.date(2022, 12, 31), datetime.date(2023, 2, 1)]
})
shas = pd.DataFrame({
    'sha': ['ae123456', 'ea654321', '123456ae'],
    'date': [datetime.date(2022, 11, 2), datetime.date(2023, 1, 1), datetime.date(2022, 11, 3)]
})

def assign_by_date(row):
    for i, sprint in iterations.iterrows():
        if sprint['start'] <= row['date'] < sprint['end']:
            return sprint['name'], sprint['start'], sprint['end']
    return np.nan, np.nan, np.nan

shas[['sprint.name', 'sprint.start', 'sprint.end']] = shas.apply(assign_by_date, axis='columns', result_type="expand")

shas
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.5/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html):

```
# Convert to datetime
iterations['start'] = pd.to_datetime(iterations['start'])
iterations['end'] = pd.to_datetime(iterations['end'])
shas['date'] = pd.to_datetime(shas['date'])

out = (pd.merge_asof(shas.sort_values('date'), iterations,
                     left_on='date', right_on='start', direction='backward')
         .drop(columns=['start', 'end']))
print(out)

# Output
        sha       date      name
0  ae123456 2022-11-02  Sprint 1
1  123456ae 2022-11-03  Sprint 1
2  ea654321 2023-01-01  Sprint 2
```